# Using SwiperJS with create-react-app. Getting import error on css

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, swiper.js

I am using that latest swiper version: swiper 8.2.4 with create-react-app.

These suggested import statements work:

```
import { Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react/swiper-react.js";
```

However I cannot get the css imports to work with any of the suggestions of import statements online.

Currently I have tried to use these three import statement but they all give me an error.

```
import "swiper/swiper.scss"; 
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'
import 'swiper/css';
```

I get this error `Module not found: Error: Package path ./swiper.scss is not exported from package /app/node_modules/swiper (see exports field in /app/node_modules/swiper/package.json)` even though I can see that file exists and is being exported in the package.json. Any ideas on this?